# How to remove the empty row when updating data to uitable

Tags: matlab

I have program to show data to `uitable`, I use this code when I want to update data, because my program is video processing.

```
    %% Database
data_plat = load('Data_PlatQ.mat');
Database_All = data_plat.Database_All;
data2 = table2cell(Database_All(strcmpi(Database_All.Plat, final_output), ...
    {'Plat', 'Nama', 'Jurusan', 'Status'}));
data2 = [get(handles.uitable1, 'Data'); data2];
    set(handles.uitable1, 'Data', unique_data2);
```

[image: data table]

I believe that empty row in there, because I update data when the table is still empty, how can I fix that??

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want. Do you want to search for empty lines and remove them?

Comment: remove that empty line, i want data start from row 1

Comment: What about `t = t(5:end, :)`?

Comment: error cause my program video processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
data2(all(cellfun('isempty',data2),2),:) = [];
```